# for expression in scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

Grr... I am really banging my head on the table wondering why this doesn't work. Could some please enlighten me?

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

def generateSubsets( occ: Occurrences ): Occurrences = {
    if (occ.isEmpty) List()
    else {
        val firstChar = occ.head._1
        val firstCharOcc: Int = occ.head._2
        val comb = for( i <- (1 to firstCharOcc); sp <- generateSubsets( occ.tail) ) 
                          yield (firstChar, i)::sp
        comb.toList
    }
}
```

Eclipse underlines the line with the for expression and tells me that "value :: is not a member of (Char, Int)"...

But when I do this:

```
val occ = List(('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('l', 2))

val t = ('m', 4)::occ
```

everything works swimmingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of sp <- generateSubsets( occ.tail) statement. generateSubsets returns a List just like you think, but then when you "assign" it to sp, sp is actually (Char, Int) instance during each iteration. Therefore you cannot have ('a', 5) :: sp because it is equivalent to ('a', 5) :: ('b', 3). 
To help you understand what is going on try this simple code

```
  def test() = {
    val i = 3
    val occ = List(('a', 1), ('b', 2))
    for( i <- (1 to i); sp <- ( occ) )
      println(i, sp)
  }

  test()
```

and look at the result

Answer (score 1):

At this line `for( i <- (1 to firstCharOcc); sp <- generateSubsets( occ.tail) )` you iterate wtih variable `sp` over list of tuples returned by `generateSubsets`. So `sp` type is also `(Char, Int)`. At the end of `for` iteration you try join two tuples `(Char, Int)` into list with method `::` which is not member of these tuples.